# Can restrict in-app purchases for certain countries?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Can you restrict in-app purchases for certain countries?
I need to enable in-app purchases only for nations Italy end england.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can upload two different apps for the specific countries with in-app.

Comment: Why? More countries more money.

Comment: @diego Did your app get rejected by restricting in-app purchases based on country or you uploaded two different binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No , You can't specially restrict In app purchase for certain countries. There have only way to do using app release restriction for certain countries. Please check iTunes -> Rights and Pricing > Select specific territories for app release restriction for certain countries.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
If I do I disable in-app purchases by code? Apple will reject my track it?

Comment: If you have country details , then you can enable/disable In app purchase . I don't think apple will reject this approach. Unless you have to upload two different app binary , one with IAP other without IAP as suggest by @iphonic